# Why is the second argument not working with strtol?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, strtol

I did this something like this:

```
/* convert the argv[1] into Integer and store the result in key
 * using library function: strtol() to do it */
char **flag = NULL;
key = strtol(argv[1], flag, 10);

// if argv[1] is not all digits
if (**flag != '\0')
{
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return 1;
}
```

But it throws a segmentation fault. I am not sure why.

In the C documentation, `strtol` is prototyped as `long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base)`. Why am I getting a segmentation fault?

And when change some parts of the code to `char *flag`, `strtol(argv[1], &flag, 10)`, and `if (*flag != '\0')`, everything works as expected.

I understand (sort of) how making the edits corrects the code. However, I do not know why the original code does not work. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not know why the original code does not work? Does anyone have any clue?

Because here

```
char **flag = NULL;
```

`flag` is set to `NULL`, then here

```
key = strtol(argv[1], flag, 10);
```

`flags`'s value (`NULL`) is passed to `strtol()`, which does not change `flags`'s value in any way, it is `NULL` before and after the call to `strtol()`.

and finally here

```
if (**flag != '\0')
```

`flag`, which has the value `NULL`, is dereferenced, which invokes undefined behaviour, which could lead to anything, which in your case is a crash.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the address of your `char *` pointer, so that `strtol` can update it.

```c
char *flag = NULL;
key = strtol(argv[1], &flag, 10);

// if argv[1] is not all digits
if (*flag != '\0')
```

After the call, the pointer will be modified to point to the end of the parsed region of the input string.

The man page wording is admittedly confusing here.

Comment: I get it what you are saying. But I am more confused about why **flag is not working?

Comment: In your code, `flag` is a `char**` and has the value `NULL`. When you pass that to `strtol`, it sees the parameter value is `NULL` and does nothing with it. When `strtol` returns the value of `flag` is still `NULL`, and thus causes a segfault when you attempt the initial dereference. You should observe this with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this simple function which multiplies a number by 2.

```
void Times2(int number, int *result)
{
  *result = number * 2;
}
```

You should call it like this:

```
int result;
Times2(3, &result);
printf("%d\n", result);
```

and the expected output would be `4`.

But if you call it like this (which is basically what you're doing when you call `strtol` in your buggy code):

```
int *result = NULL;
Times2(3, result);
printf("%d\n", result);
```

your program will most likely end up with  a segmentation fault, because in the `Times2` function you dereference a `NULL` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> Why second argument not working with `strol`?

```
char **flag = NULL;
key = strtol(argv[1], flag, 10);
```

It is working.  Passing is a *null pointer* is fine, but `flag` will not get changed in the calling code.

When the 2nd argument is a *null pointer*, nothing is updated about where the conversion ended.

---

Later code: `*flag` in `if (**flag != '\0')` is bad (undefined behavior) as that attempts to de-reference a null pointer.

---

Instead pass the address of a known pointer:

```
//char **flag = NULL;
char *flag;

//key = strtol(argv[1], flag, 10);
key = strtol(argv[1], &flag, 10);

// if (**flag != '\0')
if (*flag != '\0')
```

---

Following is a complete test conversion of a `char*` to an `int`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#incluse <ctype.h>

// Return error flag
int my_strtol(long *destination, const char *s) {
  if (destination == NULL) {
    return 1;
  } 
  if (s == NULL) {
    *destination = 0;
    return 1;
  }

  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  *destination = strtol(s, &endptr, 0); 

  // If no conversion or out-of-range
  if (s == endptr || errno == ERANGE) {
    return 1;
  }
  // I like to tolerate trailing white-space.
  while (isspace(*(const unsigned char *) endptr)) {
    endptr++;
  }
  return *endptr != '\0';
}
```